# How do I set another ViewController's property without using a segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c

From my `MCSettingsFormViewController`, I want to set `MatchCenterViewController`'s `didAddNewItem` BOOL property, but without making use of a segue.

I've imported `MatchCenterViewController.h`, which contains that property like so:

`@property (assign) BOOL didAddNewItem;`

However, when I try to set it like this: `MatchCenterViewController.didAddNewItem = YES;`, it says "property didAddNewItem not found on object of type 'MatchCenterViewController'".

I assume this is because I haven't defined what MatchCenterViewController is. If so, how can I do this property so it sets the property correctly?

**edit:**

**MatchCenterViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "WSCoachMarksView.h"

#import "SLExpandableTableView.h"



@interface MatchCenterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemSearch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemPriority;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemSearch;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMaxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMinPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryId;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemURL;
@property (assign) NSInteger expandedSection;
@property (assign) NSInteger rowCount;
@property (assign) BOOL didAddNewItem;
@property (assign) BOOL results;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *editButton;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *moreButton;
@property (strong) NSMutableSet *expandedSections;

@end

@interface MoreButton : UIButton
@property (assign) NSInteger expandedSection;
@property (assign) NSInteger sectionIndex;
@end
```

**MCSettingsFormViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"


@interface MCSettingsFormViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *minPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *maxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemPriority;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf2;

@end
```

Comment: could you post the headers for both of your view controller classes there?

Comment: Post code snippet of that part more so that we can get the situation

Comment: @MattyAyOh Just added them.

Comment: A property is attached to the OBJECT, not the CLASS.  You need to have a pointer to the OBJECT where you want to set the property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance of `MatchCenterViewController` not the name of the class.  Presumably, somewhere in your app there's a reference to a `MatchCenterViewController` object.  You can either access that reference or pick a different way of letting it know about the change.

For example, if your two controllers aren't connected to each other, you could post a notification in `MCSettingsFormViewController` and react to it in `MatchCenterViewController`.

For more specific suggestions, I'd need to know how both controllers are created and presented.

Comment: They're both created/presented using storyboard. Does that help?

Comment: A storyboard doesn't cause anything to be presented except as the initial controller or through a segue.  You said you're not using a segue, so...?

Comment: Well `MCSettingsFormViewController ` is displayed using a modal segue, and it's dismissed when I click the done button, which brings `MatchCenterViewController` back into display.

Comment: Then I think there are two reasonable options: make MatchCenterViewController a delegate of MCSettingsFormViewController when the modal segue starts and set the delegate value before it's dismissed, or have MCSettingsFormViewController post a NSNotification and let MatchCenterViewController listen for it.  Either will work and there are a bunch of samples for them.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate `MatchCenterViewController`, you could set it as a **delegate** of `MCSettingsFormViewController`.  That way, the `MatchCenterViewController` defines itself as the instantiated version of the class to be edited by the `MatchCenterViewController`.

Here is a basic tutorial for delegates: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Answer (score 0):

So based off of your headers, it looks like either your MCSettingsFormViewController doesn't have a property of type MatchCenterViewController-- or that property is private.

In the former case, you need to add a property to your MCSettingsFormViewController with type MatchCenterViewController.

In the latter you aren't initializing your MatchCenterViewController property.

So first, make sure you have that public/private property.

Then, when you first create and show your SettingsFormViewController, set this property to your MatchCenterViewController instance.  Now your SettingsForm has a reference to the proper instance you're looking for.

At this point, you can set the property on the MatchCenter